# Google cloud: accidentally deleted a default service account, where is the "projects.serviceAccounts.undelete" permission?

Tags: gcloud

I have the Owner role over the whole project. I accidentally deleted a default service account, and now I can't start any VM instance.

I learned that I can undelete the service account with the `gcloud alpha iam service-accounts undelete <ID>` command, or a similar curl command `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" "https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<project_id>/serviceAccounts/<ID>:undelete"`, but both give me the following error:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.undelete is required to perform this operation on service account
```

I can't find the iam.serviceAccounts.undelete permission anywhere. The Owner role (that I have) has all other iam.serviceAccounts permissions (create, delete, update...) but not this one.

How can I run that command?

**Edit:** My bad, I was using a wrong serviceAccount ID the whole time, I missed the last digit when I did my copy/paste... Still the error message is strange.

Comment: Please include the exact command that you're trying. I recall encountering a similar error with service account commands when I've used incorrect parameters so that may be your issue. I'm going to try to repo your issue and will update.

Comment: Thanks I edited to add the exact commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the following worked for me:

```sh
gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ROBOT} --project=${PROJECT}

ID=$(\
  gcloud iam service-accounts describe \
  ${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(uniqueId)") && echo ${ID}

gcloud iam service-accounts delete ${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud alpha iam service-accounts undelete ${ID} --project=${PROJECT}
```

yields:

```sh
restoredAccount:
  email: ${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  etag: ...
  name: projects/${PROJECT}/serviceAccounts/${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  oauth2ClientId: '${ID}'
  projectId: ${PROJECT}
  uniqueId: '${ID}'
```

I tried this on the default Compute Engine account too, thinking that may behave differently, but it undeletes too:

```sh
NUM=$(gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} \
--format="value(projectNumber)")

ID=$(\
  gcloud iam service-accounts describe \
  ${NUM}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(uniqueId)") && echo ${ID}

gcloud iam service-accounts delete ${NUM}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud alpha iam service-accounts undelete ${ID} --project=${PROJECT}
```

Filed a [FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153276760) with Google's Issue Tracker as it appears there's no way (!?) to enumerate deleted service accounts to find the uniqueId *after* deleting an account.

Comment: Hi, yeah the `gcloud alpha iam service-accounts undelete ${ID} --project=${PROJECT}` command is the one that gives me a "Permission iam.serviceAccounts.undelete is required to perform this operation" error, whether I use the --project flag or not. And I can't find such a permission in the Owner role. I hasve the ID of the service account, it is displayed in the error when I try to start or create a VM in the compute-engine.

Comment: My apologies. As you've undoubtedly checked, this permissions appears to not (yet) be available but it should be (and appears to be for me) rolled into roles/Owner. (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference). Is it possible that the service account you're trying to undelete belongs to a different project than the you're using? Could it be that the correct owning project is one where you do not have Owner?

Comment: I can't see "iam.serviceAccounts.undelete" in the reference you linked to? I see create, delete etc. but not undelete. Yes I am Owner for the correct project.

Comment: My bad, I was using a wrong serviceAccount ID the whole time, I missed the last digit when I did my copy/paste...

Comment: Glad the issue is resolved. You error and the documentation for the command both state the existence of the `undelete` permission but it appears to not be documented elsewhere nor explicitly available as part of a role.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @halfer's answer, you can potentialy find the deleted unique id by going through activity logs. Using the time should narrow the index down. Look for `Delete service account`and then it should show as `${IAM account} deleted ${unique id}`

Link: https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?project=${project}